# Linux operating system - input-output piping from parent, child, parent processes

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have some C code called a c-shell that does the following.  The parent c-shell reads in a Linux command line, and forks a child process to perform the command.  The child does not exec the command until it receives a signal from the parent that it is ready for it to execute.  It can handle input files for giving arguments to commands or it can just read them from the command line.  It can handle sending output to output files rather than just printing the executed command output to stdout.  The way that it sends the output to the output file is by the child redirecting it's stdout to a pipe, and the parent reads from this pipe once it receives the sig-child signal that the child process finished running.  It can handle multiple commands (where you put a semi-colon between commands).  It can handle piping output from the first command to a second command in the command line.  However - and this is my question - it cannot handle a command where you pipe the output of one command to be the input of the second command, and then send the output of the second command to the output file.  I'm baffled, given all the above cases work perfectly.  I can redirect output from an executed child process to the parent when it finishes so it can complete it.  I can redirect the output of the first command running to be the input to the second command running.  But I cannot do this if I try to send the output to the second command to an output file.  If this question does not make sense, I will post more specifics.

For example: if I enter into my c-shell the following command line: ls -l | grep lsOut (meaning, I do a detailed directory listing, and within that directory listing output, there are some files that contain the characters, "lsOut" (output files from the ls command), and the grep command should filter out all other files in the directory listing that do not contain those characters.  That works just fine when it prints to stdout.  When I do a command such as: ps > psOut, the output of the ps command writes to the psOut file with no problem.  However, if I do the command: ls -l | grep lsOut > lsOutFile, what happens is baffling.  It prints the first command, ls -l, to stdout and although I see in print statements that the second command, grep lsOut is being run, and should be receiving the output from ls -l as input to grep lsOut, it appears not to have any affect.  The only output is the entire ls -l directory with no grep filtering, and although it says it writes it to the output file, it does not get there.  If you want me to post a link to code, I can do that.  Thank you very much!  I spent hours trying to debug this problem.

Comment: Wall of text, hard to read, with your actual question somewhere in the middle. You may want to use a few more paragraphs.

Comment: Could there be an order problem: that `ls -l | grep lsOut > lsOutFile` is evalucated as `ls -l | (grep lsOut > lsOutFile)` instead of `(ls -l | grep lsOut) > lsOutFile`? (With the parentheses probably just for ordering, not for any other meaning.)

Comment: don't parse `ls` http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Sorry for the long paragraphs!  I do not post here very often.  Perhaps a few lines of code would more succinctly explain next time.  I did not think it was due to a paranthesis ordering thing, but I'll go back and look.  When I type the command in my console window, it works fine without parantheses, but perhaps my code has that type of issue. Also, I just found in a search a new command that may be very helpful called "tee".  It sends the output of a executed command to a file, so maybe I can avoid having to have the parent read a pipe to do that.  Thank you!!!  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

> The way that it sends the output to the output file is by the child
>   redirecting it's stdout to a pipe, and the parent reads from this pipe
>   once it receives the sig-child signal that the child process finished
>   running.

Hold it right here. As the saying goes: Do not pass "Go". Do not collect $200.

This part is already not quite right. If the child process starts spewing sufficient amount of output, you'll end up with both a hung parent and a hung child process, here.

Pipe buffers are not unlimited in size. Pipe buffers have a fixed, upper, maximum internal size. My recollection is that the default pipe buffer size is 8,192 bytes. It might actually be something else, but the actual size doesn't matter. Whatever the pipe buffer size is, once the buffer fills up, the process that's writing to the pipe buffer is put to sleep, until the reading process starts emptying the pipe by reading from it. As long as the reader and the writer processes work independently, one's reading, one's writing, everything runs smoothly. If the writer is writing faster than the reader is reading, once the number of unread characters reaches the pipe's maximum size, the kernel quietly puts the writer process to sleep, inside `write()`, until the reader catches up.

If your parent process waits for the child process to exit before it starts reading from the stdout pipe, and the child process writes more than 8,192 (or whatever the actual size is) bytes, the child process will be paused inside it's `write()` call, until the pipe's read from. And since the parent process isn't going to read from the pipe until the child process terminates, both processes will wait for each other, forever.

So, we already know that your application isn't handling this situation correctly. Although you've described a slightly different problem with your application, given that the application is not handling inter-process pipe semantics correctly, it's fairly likely that your actual problem, if not this, is closely related.

You must completely re-engineer how your applications implements inter-process piping, correctly.

Comment: I did not know that I may be exceeding the pipe buffer limit of 8192 bytes.  I don't think my entire application is incorrect, but I can see now that this is a problem if I am sending data to the parent to send to the outfile.  I found another solution that I'll try on Monday, that being the tee() command which I've not heard of until today when I was searching.  I think it sends whats in the pipe to an outfile.  That may help .  Thanks for the response!  I've not had a class on this.  Just poking around, learning on my own, was not a CS major, but have had a few CS courses here and there. ;-)

Comment: In the parent, rather than waiting for the sig-child before looking for child output, I used select() to monitor the pipe descriptor and then used an ioctl and splice() to send the output to an output file, until the child finished running, and this seemed to work.  I'm still having trouble though.  If the output from first child command is large, and you have redirected this to be the input to the next child command, can you use setbuf() to enlarge the buffer for the pipe?  I'm having trouble if I do a dir listing in first command, and try to grep for a pattern in that in next command.

Comment: setbuf() affects the size of the buffer of your process's FILE. It has no effect on internal Linux kernel pipe buffers. Furthermore, size of a pipe buffer should have no effect on a properly-implemented pipeline. Even if the internal pipe buffer was only one byte long, as long as the pipe is correctly set up, piping one program's standard output to another program's standard input is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Yes, after I wrote this, I started implementing a readers/writers implementation between my pipe writers and readers, whether parent or child process, even for the smallest of buffer cases.  It's not done yet though so I may have more questions.  Thanks for the response!